# Extracting time from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string in the format of something like this: "7:18 am"

What I'd like to be able to do is extract the "718" (not the colon in between) and the "am" into two separate variables.

I tried doing something like this, but it only returned the first integer - in this case, the 7.

```
var time = parseInt("7:18")
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "7:18 am".split(" "),
    time = parseInt(str[0].replace(":", ""), 10),
    ampm = str[1];

console.log(time, ampm);  // 718 "am"
```

Comment: This looks like it'll work.  In your output you put the 'am' in quotes - is that just to show that its data type is a string?

Comment: @joshft91 Yes, absolutely so.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be splitting it and then joining together the values that you want:

```
var timeAm = "7:18 am".split(' '); // ["7:18", "am"]
var hourMin = timeAm[0].split(':'); // ["7", "18"]
var time = parseInt(hourMin.join(''), 10); // 718
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "7:18 am";
var ampm = str.split(" ")[1];
var time = str.split(" ")[0].split(":").join("");
console.log(ampm+" "+time);
```